# Mysql compatibility between client and server of different versions

Tags: mysql, compatibility-level

How to know what version of mysql client is compatible with what version of the server?

Is there backward or forward compatibility tables from the client and/or server point of view?

**For a given version of the server, how to know which clients are compatible, and conversely?**

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of any tables or charts that document this. In general, MySQL Client is backwards compatible, and [MySQL support](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/210702)  indicates that 5.x clients can communicate with 4.x and 3.x servers.

Comment: here is (some of) the missing info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-compat-matrix/en/